# How to modify AlertDialog (Android)?

Tags: java, android

I'm a beginner for Java as well as for Android Studio so, here my problem is: I had created a alert dialog window for an activity with positive button being "OK" and negative button being "No thanks". As shown in the code below.

```
if(Times==0) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder1.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
        builder1.setTitle("Warning");
        builder1.setMessage("Rooting of a phone may void your Warranty in most of the cases,so it is adviced to proceed at your own risk");
        builder1.setCancelable(true);

        builder1.setPositiveButton(
                "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Times += 1;
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        builder1.setNegativeButton(
                "No Thanks",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();

                    }
                });
 }
```

It was going fine but now the catch is I want it to be displayed only once if the user clicks the "OK" button and don't want to show it again if the user clicked "OK". I had created a variable `times` in my class and initialised it to zero as shown below.

```
public class rootingRooting extends AppCompatActivity {

int Times=0;
```

and put the complete `AlertDialog` in the if loop and incremented it's value when the user clicked "OK" so that the loop may execute only once if the user clicked "OK", but it is of no use whenever I open the activity the alert box is being displayed inspite of clicking "OK". So, now the things i want to do happen is:

1. The alert box should not be displayed if the user once clicked "OK".
2. If the user clicked the "no Thanks" button, I want to take him to the home activity. So, how should I use the intent with the "no thanks" button?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `SharedPreferenes` to save data persistently, local variables will not help.
something like this:

**EDIT** As per your request, I have added a sample activity class to show the whole process. See the comments in between for more info

**EDIT 2** See the code after *//Second Edit comment*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        SharedPreferences prefs;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                //When the activity starts, we look into the shared prefs and get an int of name "ok_clicked" from it.
                //0 will be the default value of the int if there is no int stored in sharedPreferences.
                prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
                int times = prefs.getInt("ok_clicked", 0);
                //if the times value is 0, we will open the dialog, otherwise nothing happens
                if (times==0){
                    openDialog();
                }
            }
            //Read This comment First: We will create a Method, which create an alert Dialog.
            private void openDialog(){
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                dialog.setTitle("Test").setMessage("Lorem ipsum dolor");
                dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //When OK button is clicked, an int with value of 1 will be saved in sharedPreferences.
                        prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                        editor.putInt("ok_clicked", 1);
                        editor.apply();
                    }
                });
                dialog.setNegativeButton("No Thanks", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //Second Edit: To open another acitivty on No Thanks Button
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);                                   
                    startActivity(intent);
                   }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you doctor wilson,but being a newbie in java as well as android i just can t figure out where i had to use what i expect you  to be a bit more specific,to be frank this is the firs time i am hearing of sharedPreferences and i tried a bit to put the first block after the declaration of my class and imported the required files but stillit is showing as "cannot resolve symbol putInt" or "cannot resolve symbol apply" Thank you..

Comment: Dont put the first block after activity declaration, put it in OnClick of your AlertDialog "OK" button. And put the other two blocks in place of your if (times==0), when you are calling the AlertDialog

Comment: Thank you drWilson.I figured it out and now it is working as i itended it to and one more thing is the second question i asked now how can i use an intent in the "no thanks" button if the user clicked will take them directly to home or another activity.could you kindly please answer this also??

Comment: Glad it helped, ( I have updated the answer anyway). See my second edit for your second question.

Comment: See the `dialog.SetNegativeButton` method. In place of `MyActivity` write the name of your current activity, and in place of `HomeActivity`, write the name of the activity which you want to open. If you only want to close the current activity, call `finish()` instead of using intent.

Comment: Got it Dr, u had been of great help to me and solved a major problem in my small app.i don't know how many times i had thanked u but thanks a lot for taking all the pain to type down a complete example..Cheers...!!!

Comment: That's what StackOverflow is for. Good luck with your coding